# Is using self as an attribute to outside method a good practice?

Tags: python

I am trying to save me from repeating code in two classes, I have tested the following snippet and it works, I am wondering if it is a good practice or should I consider using inheritance. In that case is there something particularly wrong about this approach?

```
def do_something_with_self(obj):
    print 'Hello, I was called from %s' % obj.name

class A(object):
    name = "Class A"

    def do_something(self):
        do_something_with_self(self)    

class B(object):
    name = "Class B"

    def do_something(self):
        do_something_with_self(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    a.do_something()
    b.do_something()
```

Comment: Two things. One: An instance always knows the name of it's class: `self.__class__.__name__`. You do not need to hardcode it. Two: Instead of `def do_something(self): do_something_with_self(self)` you can just `do_something = do_something_with_self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good practice. In general, you should avoid inheritance when you have a choice between inheritance and another simple mechanism for code sharing.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good practice if the situation calls for it. Sometimes an object needs to be passed to a function that works with objects of that type without being a method of that type of object, and that's the way to do it. For example, your object might have a logging function that includes a `dir()` of the object - `dir(self)` would be the way to do that.

However, if `A` and `B` are really both objects of the same overarching kind (like `Letter`), I would recommend using inheritance.